# Is there a way to override layouts in NextJS 14?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, next.js14

I have what I would guess is a pretty common setup in NextJS 13/14 app router. I have a `layout.tsx` file which shows my sticky navbar at the top of the screen for navigation purposes:

```
import "./globals.css";
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <div className="relative">
          <!-- My navbar is here --> 
          <div className="sticky top-0 z-50 h-16 w-full bg-blue-200" />;
          <div className="px-4">
            <div className="flex-grow p-6 md:overflow-y-auto ">{children}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

And then I create my `page.tsx` file, which has a modal in it:

```
import Modal from "./Modal";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-4">
      <div className="mx-auto">
        <p>Hello world!</p>
        <div className="w-full h-full">
          <Modal />
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Here is the Modal code:

```
"use client";

import { Dialog, Transition } from "@headlessui/react";
import { Fragment, useState } from "react";

export default function Modal() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  function toggleOpen() {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button
        className=" border-2 rounded-lg border-gray-400"
        onClick={toggleOpen}
      >
        Open me!
      </button>
      <Transition appear show={isOpen} as={Fragment}>
        <Dialog as="div" className="relative z-10" onClose={toggleOpen}>
          <Transition.Child
            as={Fragment}
            enter="ease-out duration-300"
            enterFrom="opacity-0"
            enterTo="opacity-100"
            leave="ease-in duration-200"
            leaveFrom="opacity-100"
            leaveTo="opacity-0"
          >
            <div className="fixed inset-0 bg-black/25" />
          </Transition.Child>

          <div className="fixed inset-0 overflow-y-auto">
            <div className="flex min-h-full items-center justify-center p-4 text-center">
              <Dialog.Panel className="text-center w-full max-w-md transform overflow-hidden rounded-2xl bg-white p-6 align-middle shadow-xl transition-all">
                <Dialog.Title
                  as="h3"
                  className={`text-black text-lg font-medium leading-6`}
                >
                  {"This is a header"}
                </Dialog.Title>

                <div className="flex mt-4 text-center w-full  justify-center">
                  <div className="ml-3">
                    <button className="rounded-md" onClick={toggleOpen}>
                      Close modal
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Dialog.Panel>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Dialog>
      </Transition>
    </>
  );
}
```

Which gives us something like this:

[image: example-site]

And when I open the modal, something uglier:

[image: example-site-open-modal]

My issue is that when I open the dialog, the modal transition does NOT obscure `layout.tsx` (e.g. the blue header), but it obscures the rest of the page not defined by the layout component (e.g. the children of the layout). I know this is because of the way that Nextjs nests components: [image: NextJS component nesting]

So I suppose my question is, isn't the fact that any full-screen overlay doesn't go over top of the code in `layout.tsx` a serious shortcoming of using `layout.tsx` for any sort of navigation/permanent fixture purposes? If the layout will always sit on top of any modal overlay, won't that always just be pretty ugly, no matter what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can just be solved with css as opposed to needing to do anything funky with next's project structure. It looks like the sticky header has a z-index of 50, so your transition component needs to have a higher z-index to show up on top.

Additionally, the sticky header's width issue is probably being caused by a scrollbar appearing/disappearing after disabling scrolling when the modal is opened up? In that case you can just set the header's width to `100vw` instead of `100%`.